# validate.js always validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

My jquery:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(function() {
            var v = $("#form1").validate({
                ignore: ':hidden',
                rules: {
                    txtTest: { required: true }

                },
                messages: {
                    txtTest: "User name is required."

                }

            });

            $("#btnTest").click(function() {
                if (v.form()) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Fail");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and my HTML is:

```
 <input type="text" id="txtTest" />
 <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Test" />
```

although `txtTest` is blank its fire `alert("Success");`.Never enter in `else` condition.Never fire `alert("Fail");`.It doesn't show any error in firebug.I am unable to  find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: I got a error `v.validate is not a function` when i use `v.validate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem you're having is that each input or select in a form must have a `name` attribute.

So your input should look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTest" name="txtTest" />
```

Other than that, all your demos look fine to me - I simplified @Tats_innit demo to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/LjMQ2/2/

If you need to do particular things when the form submission succeeds of fails, the right place would be in the `submitHandler` or `invalidHandler`.  If you want to trigger validation, a reasonable thing to do is to do a `$('form').submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Xc3d5/ **further with email** http://jsfiddle.net/LjMQ2/1/

See validation `element` api : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

Use of `v.form()` wont do anything, I reckon use `.element` and then pass the element you want to validate. Rest the demo will make it clear.

Hope this helps :)

**code**

```
var v = $("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        console.log('successful submit');
        return false;
    }
});

$("#btnTest").click(function() {
    if (v.element('#txtTest')) {
        alert("Success");
    }
    else {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: how to handle with email field in this method?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email Should help, and pass it same as this `v.element('#txtTest')` to invoke validation but link should help.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal made a small extra email demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LjMQ2/1/ Have fun! `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Don't say `Use of v.form() wont do anything`.Here is a working demo  with  `v.form()`.http://jsfiddle.net/shree/CBZSw/

Comment: Any way thanks for help.I find my mistake inside your ans.So i accept it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very roundabout way of using Validate, if you setup the form correctly, nothing special has to be done.  See my answer